# Image Gallery Recommendations For Website

Tags: html, php, mysql, gallery

I am looking for a gallery plugin for a new website I am working on but I'm having trouble finding one with all of the features that I need. I have looked at a few so far, including [Coppermine](http://coppermine-gallery.net/) and [Piwigo](http://piwigo.org/), however most don’t have a tidy, modern, responsive design “out of the box” and there aren’t many responsive themes available for them. I am hoping to find a gallery with the following features:

- Search (keywords and description)
- Picture details, including: description, title, photographer and date
  taken
- Ability to add comments (either built-in feature or easy to add)
- Responsive UI (or alternatively a good range of responsive themes to
  choose from)
- Batch uploading of images
- Easy to use interface (to manage and upload images)
- Ability to add watermarks and/or restrict people from downloading images would be a plus
- Add an image to multiple categories
- Well documented with easy theme manipulation/creation
- User registration would also be good with the ability to add images to favorites etc. however there needs to be a way to restrict the user from uploading their own images

I would really appreciate some recommendations for gallery plugins (free or paid and preferably using PHP/MYSQL) that would meet most, if not all, of the requirements above.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Gallery3](http://galleryproject.org/) it meets all you feature requests except for the feature request Responsive UI. Though there might be a responsive layout out there.

These feature requests are met:

- Search (keywords and description)
- Picture details, including: description, title, photographer and date taken
- Ability to add comments (either built-in feature or easy to add)
- Batch uploading of images
- Easy to use interface (to manage and upload images)
- Ability to add watermarks and/or restrict people from downloading images
- Add an image to multiple categories
- Well documented with easy theme manipulation/creation
- User registration
- Written in PHP
- Uses MySQL